# How to prove the equivalent condition for QE?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory

I can't prove that the QE (quantifier elimination) is equivalent to this statement:

> If $M$, $N$ are two models of $T$ and $N$ is $|M|^+$-saturated, every
>   embedding from a substructure $A \subseteq M$ to $N$ can be extended to an
>   embedding from $B$ to $N$ where $B$ properly extends $A$.

For one side I think since we have QE, every embedding is elementary, so when the new points are added we can take its type over the elements of previous step and since $N$ is saturated the projection of this type will be realised in $N$ so we can extend the embedding. (I'm not sure if this is true...)

Comment: You should double check the statement, as it is it is poorly formulated and not entirely clear. I guess it should say "If $M$ and $N$ are models of $T$ and $N$ is $|M|^+$-saturated, every embedding from a substructure $A \subseteq M$ to $N$ can be extended to an embedding from $B \subseteq M$ to $N$ where $B$ properly extends $A$."

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, I had  forgot to check it after I wrote it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was recently asked and answered on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/335632/reference-request-quantifier-elimination-test).

The result you're looking for is Proposition 4.3.28 in Marker's *Model Theory: An Introduction*.